# kubectl pod errors with "container init caused: rootfs_linux.go:75: mounting ... mount through procfd: not a directory: unknown"

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to mount two files from a k8s secret into a pod but I'm getting this verbose error:

> Error: failed to create containerd task: OCI runtime create failed:
> container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused:
> process_linux.go:545: container init caused: rootfs_linux.go:75:
> mounting
> "/var/lib/kubelet/pods/68b02215-f757-4bae-a427-71cac2e3e206/volume-subpaths/nginx-ssl/nginx/1"
> to rootfs at "/etc/nginx/conf.d/fullchain.pem" caused: mount through
> procfd: not a directory: unknown

Here is my deployment yaml, everything worked fine till I added the `nginx-ssl` volume / volume mounts.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-bot-proxy
  labels:
    app: nginx-proxy-bot
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-proxy-bot
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-proxy-bot
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.23
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        - containerPort: 443
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d 
          name: nginx-conf
        - name: nginx-ssl
          mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d/fullchain.pem
          subPath: fullchain.pem
        - name: nginx-ssl
          mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d/privkey.pem
          subPath: privkey.pem
      volumes:
      - name: nginx-ssl
        secret:
          secretName: nginx-ssl
          items:
            - key: privkey.pem
              path: privkey.pem
            - key: fullchain.pem
              path: fullchain.pem
      - name: nginx-conf
        configMap:
          name: nginx-bot-proxy-config
          items:
            - key: default.conf
              path: default.conf
```

The secret:

```
kubectl describe secret nginx-ssl
Name:         nginx-ssl
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Type:  Opaque

Data
====
fullchain.pem:  5745 bytes
privkey.pem:    1704 bytes
```

What am I doing wrong? What does the error message mean, it seems to imply it's not a directory (it's not?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are not able to mount a volume under another volume...

Fixed by just using a mount path outside of the `/etc/nginx/conf.d`.

```
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d 
          name: nginx-conf
        - name: nginx-ssl
          mountPath: /etc/nginx/the-ssl/fullchain.pem
          subPath: fullchain.pem
        - name: nginx-ssl
          mountPath: /etc/nginx/the-ssl/privkey.pem
          subPath: privkey.pem
```